# Strange linearity test for ANCOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, linear-model, ancova

There is an easy way to test the linearity hypothesis for a simple regression model $y \sim {\cal N}(\alpha+\beta x,\sigma^2)$: calling $H_0$ this model, perform a test against the ANOVA model $H_1$ obtained by considering the (numeric) covariate $x$ as a (qualitative) factor. Of course this requires to have several values of $y$ for each value of $x$. In R :

```
fit0 <- lm(y ~ x)
fit1 <- lm(y ~ factor(x))
anova(fit0, fit1)
```

This is quite sensible. But I have seen somewhere a linearity test for an ANCOVA model and I'm puzzling over what it means. The R code, denoting by $x$ the numeric covariate and $A$ the qualitative factor, is like:

```
fit0 <- lm(y ~ x + A + x:A)
fit1 <- lm(y ~ x + A + x:A + factor(x))
anova(fit0, fit1)
```

That means that $H_0$ is the classical ANCOVA model with interaction and $H_1$ is the bigger model obtained by adding the covariate $x$ considered as a factor.

Does it make sense for you ? I cannot figure out how to interpret model $H_1$.

Comment: Your first snippet is clearly testing whether non-linearity effect is significant. As for the second snippet, I can't understand if there any use of it: two identical full ANCOVA models, and one of them with additional term added. It looks like testing if this addition improves the model, which has nothing to do with the issue of linearity

Comment: @ttnphns This is exactly my feeling. Moreover there are unestimable parameters in the second model. I have seen this test in a SAS code written by a colleague of mine. I appreciate other advices before saying him this test has no sense, or at least nothing to do with the issue of linearity. Thanks.

Comment: I agree: if $x$ is really continuous then there are too many parameters to be able to estimate them; if not, then it's the same logic as the first pair of models. It would make more sense to test adding a quadratic term in $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the method used by colleague **is correct** but this is not the one I showed in my question: it is

```
fit0 <- lm(y ~ x + A + x:A)
fit2 <- lm(y ~ x + A + x:A + factor(x):A)
anova(fit0, fit2)
```

This still sounds strange, but actually this is tricky. The natural way to test linearity is:

```
fit0 <- lm(y ~ x + A + x:A)
fit1 <- lm(y ~ factor(x) + A + factor(x):A)
anova(fit0, fit1)
```

That is, we test $H_0\colon\{\text{ANCOVA model}\}$ vs $H_1\colon\{\text{2-WAY ANOVA model}\}$ by considering in $H_1$ that the numerical covariate is categorical.

Let's consider an example:

```
y=c(161,160,178,187,171,194,
    151,192,150,172,170,192,
    162,195,174,161,193,151,
    194,184,199,160,163,171,
    176,181,201,202,154,151,
    193,166,161,186,198,182)
A=c("S","T","T","S","S","U",
    "T","T","S","S","U","S",
    "T","S","U","U","T","T",
    "S","S","U","T","S","T",
    "S","T","S","T","T","S",
    "T","S","T","T","S","S")
x=c(1,1,2,3,2,3,
    1,3,1,2,2,3,
    2,3,2,1,6,1,
    3,2,3,1,1,2,
    2,2,3,3,1,1,
    3,1,1,2,4,2)
> fit0 <- lm(y ~ x + A + x:A)
> fit1 <- lm(y ~ factor(x) + A + factor(x):A)
> anova(fit0, fit1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: y ~ x + A + x:A
Model 2: y ~ factor(x) + A + factor(x):A
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1     30 2367.2                                  
2     25  990.8  5    1376.4 6.9459 0.0003439 ***
```

Now consider the following problem: **how to get this $p$-value with SAS ?**. There's no equivalent of `anova(fit0, fit1)` in SAS, and the ANOVA table of $H_1$ does *not* provide the desired $p$-value:

```
> anova(fit1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
factor(x)    4 8491.3 2122.82 53.5632 6.678e-12 ***
A            2    4.0    1.98  0.0501    0.9513    
factor(x):A  4   70.0   17.49  0.4413    0.7775    
Residuals   25  990.8   39.63
```

Thus, someone (I don't know who is he/she), has invented the following "strange" model:

```
fit2 <- lm(y ~ x + A + x:A + factor(x):A)
```

This is the ANCOVA model $H_0$ with an additional term: the interaction of the factor and of the numerical covariate considered as a categorical variable. I say it is strange because I have some pain to interpret it. Moreover **it has some unestimable parameters**:

```
> coef(fit2)
  (Intercept)             x            AT            AU          x:AT          x:AU AS:factor(x)2 
   144.933333     13.266667      3.866667     -1.683333     -5.900000      4.483333      5.533333 
AT:factor(x)2 AU:factor(x)2 AS:factor(x)3 AT:factor(x)3 AU:factor(x)3 AS:factor(x)4 AT:factor(x)4 
    12.066667     -6.750000      9.066667     24.766667            NA            NA            NA 
AU:factor(x)4 AS:factor(x)6 AT:factor(x)6 AU:factor(x)6 
           NA            NA            NA            NA
```

because **its design matrix is not of full rank**:

```
> X <- model.matrix(fit2)
> qr(X)$rank
[1] 11
> dim(X)
[1] 36 18
```

But **this model is useful**: its ANOVA table (available in SAS) provides the desired $p$-value:

```
> anova(fit2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
x            1 6607.4  6607.4 166.7199 1.471e-12 ***
A            2  156.8    78.4   1.9785 0.1593386    
x:A          2  424.5   212.3   5.3559 0.0115905 *  
A:factor(x)  5 1376.4   275.3   6.9459 0.0003439 ***
Residuals   25  990.8    39.6
```

What's happening ? I don't totally understand all the details yet. Actually I don't know how linear model fitting works with unestimable parameters ?

But first note that the `Residuals` line is the same for `fit1` and `fit2`:

```
        Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
Residuals   25  990.8    39.6
```

Moreover, the two ANOVA tables have the same total sum of squares:

```
> cumsum(anova(fit1)$Sum)
    [1] 8491.267 8495.236 8565.200 9556.000
    > cumsum(anova(fit2)$Sum)
[1] 6607.444 6764.270 7188.800 8565.200 9556.000
```

This occurs because the design matrix in `fit1` and `fit2` span the same vector space, but in `fit2` there's like a "removing of the singular part" of the design matrix (I guess this step uses generalized inverse for matrices but I don't remember how it works). Moreover, the first three lines of `anova(fit2)` and `anova(fit0)` are the same:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
x            1 6607.4  6607.4 166.7199 1.471e-12 ***
A            2  156.8    78.4   1.9785 0.1593386    
x:A          2  424.5   212.3   5.3559 0.0115905 *
```

Thus we mathematically conclude that the $p$-value of the 4th line of `anova(fit2)` is the same as the Fisher test `anova(fit0, fit1)`.

Roughly speaking, the philosophy of this trick is : enlarge model $H_0$ by adding one categorical variable such that the bigger model, *"even if it is wrong"*, has a design matrix which span the same vector space as model $H_1$, *"after removing the singular part of this matrix"*. This latter point is the one I don't master.